# Выбор времени для глагола: настоящее или прошедшее?

Tags: грамматика, времена

Какой из вариантов верный?

> По тексту письма видно, что автор спешит.

> По тексту письма видно, что автор спешил.

И почему?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нужен **конкретный текст эпизода,** чтобы сделать вывод. Я полагаю, что оба варианта возможны.

**В  первом случае** даются размышления в настоящий момент, вывод еще не сделан.

**А во втором варианте** ситуация обдумывается повторно, уже какие-то предварительные выводы сделаны.

Но это мои предположения, а вообще-то нужен контекст.